# rollup fields on the object workaround

Tags: roll-up-summary

I know there is a limitation on how many rollup fields you can have on each object. And with the help of salesforce it is possible to increase the limitation.

We have gone through the security review and ready to put our app on app-exchange. What if people start buying our app and install on to their org is it still able to increase the limit or I need salesforce to increase the limit before putting on the appexhange?

Answer (score 4):

If an organization has reached its limit of rollup summary fields or they're close and your app will push them over the limit, installation of your app from the AppExchange will fail. The organization will have to increase its limit prior to installation and this should probably be outlined well in your documentation and installation instructions.

You should not however, need to do anything prior to posting you app on the AppExchange as this is really a customer by customer, case by case problem.

In terms of architecture, using rollup summary fields may not be the best path forward, especially if you are going to commonly run against this limit. As an alternative, you may consider rolling up parent child totals with apex.